# How do I cause my LEDs to light in a random fashion using $urandom_range?

Tags: system-verilog

I realize this is a very basic thing but I am new to systemverilog and FPGAs and can't for the life of me seem to get this to work. I am using an FPGA with 16 active high leds which I can initialize as output logic [15:0] led and I can cause one of the LEDs to light by writing led[x] = 1; where x is a number between 0 and 15 or cause however many to light by writing led = 16b'abcdefghijclmnop where each letter to the right of ' either a 1 or 0.

However I want them to light in a random fashion.

**I originally tried writing**

```
led[0] = $urandom_range(0,1); 
led[1] = $urandom_range(0,1);
.
.
led[15] = $urandom_range(0,1);
```

**and that did not work.
Then I tried writing**

```
logic [0:0] led1 = $urandom_range(0,1);
led[0] = led1;
```

**and that did not work.**

**I tried:**

```
bit [0:0] led1 = $urandom_range(0,1);
led[0] = led1;
```

**and that did not work
With both bit and logic type I tried:**

```
type [0:0] led1 = $urandom_range(0,1);

if(led1)
   led[0] = 1;
else
   led[0] = 0;
```

**and I also tried:**

```
if (led1>0)
   led[0] = 1;
else
   led[0] = 0;
```

**and neither worked.
And I tried:**

```
logic [15:0] led1 = $urandom_range(0,1);

led = led1;
```

And that did not work.

I tried all of these in both initial and always_begin and always_ff blocks with the appropriate assignment statements and I still cannot get the LEDs to light at all using $urandom_range()

Comment: I'm not sure. How would I find out? It's a BASYS3. I don't get any sythesis or implementation errors or warnings. I'm using Vivado.

Comment: check synthesis warnings and errors.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I meant I don't know if the board supports the command and I have not been able to find any documentation concerning that. I am not getting any warnings or errors when I synthesize or implement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would be very surprised if the system task `$urandom` or `$urandom_range` would be synthesizable.

Whenever your are using any HDL to actual synthesize digital circuits, you need to keep in mind you are not "programming" but your are actually designing logic circuits. So to actually create some random value you would need to create some-kind of a Random Number generator.

I would suggest to use some kind of simple LFSR to actually generate some pseudo-random value. Or take one from the library of the tool that your are using. Or you can use something similar which is in following snippet (not sure if it is synthesizable though):

```
module PSRG_LFSR (clock,rst_n,halfword_out);
  input clock,rst_n;
  output logic[15:0] halfword_out;

  logic new_bit;
  assign new_bit = halfword_out[9] ^ halfword_out[7] ^ halfword_out[5];

  always@(posedge clock) begin
    if ( rst_n != 1'b1 ) begin
      halfword_out = 16'hDEAD;
    end 
    else begin
      halfword_out = {halfword_out,new_bit};
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Then you can just instantiate this LFSR and connect it to the `LED` in your code. LFSR will need to some proper clock though:

```
...
PSRG_LFSR LFSR_i (.clock(clock),.rst_n(reset),.halfword_out(LED));
...
```

Answer (score -1):

VHDL code is converted into netlist made up of logic gates and flip flops when synthesis is carried out. For this to be possible the VHDL description must meet certain strict criteria else the synthesis tool will reject it.

The functions you are using to generate random number cannot be run through a synthesis tool. You should be able to use them to assign an initial value but they cannot be run in hardware on the FPGA!

The simplest method to use is to use a linear feedback shift register (LFSR) which uses feedback from specific taps to get a maximum length repeating output sequence. This is the simplest thing you could do and is almost trivial to do in hardware.

The Xilinx app notes XAPP052 and XAPP210 might help you in this regard. They both contain a table showing the taps to be used in the feedback loop for a LFSR of a given length to give the maximum length of repeating sequence.

If you want to have a more robust method which will most certainly not be required for LEDs then please have a look at this xoshiro / xoroshiro generators:

https://prng.di.unimi.it/

https://github.com/jorisvr/vhdl_prng

Comment: The LFSR is the simplest way to create random numbers inside the FPGA. It is the most often used method as well and is sufficient for most applications. I wonder what the down vote is for?